# how can I add data to posts in WordPress that can be retrieved by WP Rest API

Tags: wordpress

I used [Custom Field Suite](http://customfieldsuite.com/) to add fields to all WordPress posts, but the field data does not show when I retrieve post data through the [WP Rest API](http://wp-api.org/) using [/posts](http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts) on a stand alone site.

Is there a way to add the CFS data so that it is retrieved by wp-json/posts REST calls?  It feels like I just need to put a CFS()->get call in the right place.  Or just a basic way to add data to posts so they are retrievable in REST calls?

I've added github issues for [CFS](https://github.com/mgibbs189/custom-field-suite/issues/266) and [WP-API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1201), but any help or direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most easiest way to add custom fields in the [WP Rest API](http://wp-api.org/) is to used  [Advance Custom field](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin, with following small plugin extension.

[Add Advance Custom Fields to JSON API](https://github.com/PanManAms/WP-JSON-API-ACF)

Answer (score 6):

If someone use WP REST API V2, this may help:

adding this to `function.php` adds CFS for custom post type and standard posts (project in my case)

```
function cfs_to_json_api($post_response, $post, $context) {
$post_response->data['CFS']=CFS()->get( false, $post->ID, array( 'format' => 'raw' ) );
return $post_response ;
}

add_filter('rest_prepare_project', 'cfs_to_json_api', 12, 3);
add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'cfs_to_json_api', 12, 3);
```

**IMPORTANT:**

True: 
add_filter ('rest_prepare_post' 'function', 12, 3);

False: 
add_filter ('json_prepare_post' 'function', 12, 3); //WRONG

If is Custom Post Type:
add_filter ('rest_prepare_{$post_type}' 'function', 12, 3);

EXAMPLE: Name post type = product; 
add_filter ('rest_prepare_product' 'function', 12, 3);

Comment: This does not seem to work, I am afraid. Is there something we are missing here?